# Vba Columns into Rows

Tags: excel, macros, vba

[The image is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxYoR.jpg)

I want to select the data in yellow and insert into rows in another sheet without repetition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
Dim i as Integer, iWS2
Dim WS1 as WorkSheet, WS2 as WorkSheet

Set WS1 = Sheets("Name WS1")
Set WS2 = Sheets("Name WS2")
i = 2
iWS2 = 1

Do Until WS1.Cells(i, 11).value = ""
    If LCase(WS1.Cells(i, 11).value) = "nationality" Then
        WS2.Range(Cells(iWS2, 1), Cells(iWS2, 13)).value = WS1.Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 13)).value
        WS2.Cells(iWS2, 14).value = WS1.Cells(i + 1, 13).value
            'I'd recommend to put all info of every student in the same row
            'Do the same for the other cells
        iWS2 = iWS2 + 1
    End If

    i = i + 1
Loop

Set WS1 = Nothing
Set WS2 = Nothing
```

Comment: Yes,that's the logic,but it repeats  the same row as many times as many student_infos,for each student we take from the first sheet.I want to enter the values for each student in a row one time.
 @RobK

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but haven't you forgotten to add the lines of code for the other student infos? `WS2.Cells(iWS2, 15).value = WS1.Cells(i + 2, 13).value`, etcetera?

Comment: I did that. The logic is right.I guess I have to manage the indexes. When the condition is accompilshed. I give i a new index value r And move with r then. @RobK

Comment: Which row is being repeated? On WS1 or WS2?

Comment: I have 2 conditions.I just needed to change their places.If the first condition is accomplished,set the index which will  be used by the other condition.Thank you anyway.